# Storing data in a file (C++)

Tags: c++, storing-data

I am fairly new to C++ and I am currently trying to save some of the data that my program produces in a file. My code outputs values for two variables, A and B. Considering I am aiming to plot A vs B, what is the best way of approaching this? I was thinking of creating an array, but perhaps creating a .txt file with **two columns** will be easier.

I have tried looking into it and it appears that this is easier said than done. I don't know much about pointers, but I suspect I may need to know more before attempting this.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int a = 10, b = 5; 0 < a < 20 && b < 50;)
    {
        int B = b + a;
        cout << "B = " << B << endl;
        int A = a - b;
        cout << "A = " << A << endl;
        b = B;
        a = A;
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
B = 15
A = 5
B = 20
A = -10
B = 10
A = -30
B = -20
A = -40
B = -60
A = -20
B = -80
A = 40
B = -40
A = 120
B = 80
A = 160
```

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Does the file need to be human readable?

Comment: I guess not, as long as I am able to plot the data using, say, Mathematica.

Comment: get rid of the newline after "B", so that "A" writes to the same line

Comment: `0 < a < 20` Doesn't do what you probably think it does. It is always `true` regardless of `a`. What you probably meant is `a > 0 && a < 20`

Comment: Does Mathematica support CSV data files? I mean that should be very easy to implement.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `ifstream` and `ofstream` for filesystem operations...

Comment: Answering my own question. CSV should work: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/CSV.html

Comment: @user2079303 Ah, ok thanks. This is just a test code so it doesn't really matter but I have noted what you said :)

Comment: You can always use cout as you are doing and just pipe the output to a file using the shell. `$ ./a.out > plot-data.csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store data in a file, here's how you'd go about doing that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("filename.txt");
    for (int a = 10, b = 5; 0 < a && a < 20 && b < 50;)
    {
        int B = b + a;
        int A = a - b;
        fout << B << " " << A << endl;
        b = B;
        a = A;
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: You perpetuate the OP's error in the comparison (`0 < a < 20` is not correct in C++). Also, you could pass the file name to the constructor instead of opening separately.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that creating a `.txt` file with two columns is easier, and the file you generated can be easily imported in various programming and plotting environments like Mathematica, MATLAB, R, and Python. You should
do something like:

```
 cout<<A<<'\t'<<B<<endl;
```

this is separated by TAB. Or you can separate it with space using `" "`.
For file writing, checkout the tutorial here:http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 1):

Look into Fstream.  I am pretty sure thats how you can save data to a txt file.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/